# How to open MATLAB coder app in 2011 version and 2021(MATLAB online)?

Tags: matlab

I used 2015 version of MATLAB and it had a tab named"apps" but currently i have access to 2011 version, but there isn't any such tab in 2011 version

Also i tried to check in 2021 version available on MATLAB online,but couldn't see apps tab

So in such versions, how we can open apps? Forexample MATLAB coder app for C/C++ code generation

Answer (score 0):

To open the MATLAB Coder app in MATLAB R2011b (desktop), you can type the following command in the Command Window:

```
coder
```

Note: The above will open the R2011b version of the MATLAB Coder app, which has a different look and feel compared to the latest version (R2021a).

Unfortunately, the MATLAB Coder app is not supported in MATLAB Online as of the latest release (R2021a). However, you can use the [codegen](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/codegen.html?) command which is the CLI equivalent of the MATLAB Coder app.

Answer (score 0):

As @ami91 mentioned, the MATLAB Coder App doesn't support MATLAB Online as of R2021b. MATLAB Online does support `coderTypeEditor` [doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/define-and-edit-input-properties-by-using-the-coder-type-editor.html) to create `coder.Type` objects and

```matlab
cfg = coder.config;
open cfg
```

to open an app for editing a config object for use with `codegen`  [doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/specify-configuration-parameters-at-the-command-line-by-using-dialog-box.html). Those can bridge the gap until the Coder App supports MATLAB Online.